# Access SQL Query: Extract Email before "SMTP" in string

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Is there an expression to extract the email before the characters "SMTP" ...or truncate the string starting with "SMTP" in the following string example?

xyz@xyz.comSMTPfirst last (xyz@xyz.com)

Problem: Outlook exports emails with concatenated data.

Resolved...

I entered the code as follows and it works!

```
Contacts: Left([Email],InStr([Email],"SMTP")-1)
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

In Access' query designer it would be:

```
EMail: Left([YourField], InStr([YourField],"SMTP")-1)
```

In SQL:

```
Select *, Left([YourField], InStr([YourField],"SMTP")-1) As EMail
From YourTable
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `LEFT` and `PATINDEX` to return characters to the left of the pattern.

```
SELECT CleanEmail = 
    CASE WHEN @line LIKE '%SMTP%'
        THEN LEFT(@line, PATINDEX('%SMTP%', @line) - 1)
        ELSE NULL
    END
```